# Windows SSH send wrong control command on enter

Tags: windows-10, ssh, cmd.exe

With the new SSH Client and Server now build in into windows I tried to ssh into my raspberry pi.
All went successful but then I encountered an issue when trying to 'enter' when, for example, trying to save a file in nano.
It seems the wrong command is send as nano says "Unbound key: ^J", so I suspect ^M should be send when pressing enter.
Can this behavior be changed?

EDIT: This does work perfectly fine in Tera Term, so its not the RPi settings that cause the issue.

Comment: Report the issue through the Feedback UWP application.  The feature is still very early and likely has numerous issues like you describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed in one of the more recent versions.